# Dplyr calculate mean and variance without all the data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that started out like the following:

```
set.seed(50)
n <- 20
s_num <- c(10,20,30)
counts <- c(0,1,2,3,4)

strata <- sample(s_num, n, replace=T)
sites <- seq(1, n, by=1)
observed <- sample(counts, n, replace=T)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(strata,sites,observed))
```

I can group by strata and get the means and variance using dplyr by:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(strata) %>%
  summarise(mcount = mean(observed),
            varcount = var(observed))
```

The problem is 0 counts are no longer in the database:

```
df3 <- subset(df,observed != 0)
```

So the mean and variance now aren't correct:

```
df4 <- df3 %>%
  group_by(strata) %>%
  summarise(mcount = mean(observed),
            varcount = var(observed))
```

But I have the count of sites:

```
site_count <- df %>%
  group_by(strata) %>%
  summarise(count_plot = n_distinct(sites))
```

Can I still use dplyr to calculate the mean variance without the 0s? Mean actually isn't too hard by merging site counts to df; variance is harder. I can add back the 0 rows if needed, but wanted to see if there is a simple way around it if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually calculate the mean and variance from the formulas, once you  have `count_plot` computed.

Variance computed as `sum((x - mean(x))^2)/(length(x) - 1)`

```
df3 %>% 
  left_join(site_count) %>% 
  group_by(strata) %>%
  summarise(N        = unique(count_plot),
            mcount   = sum(observed)/N,
            varcount = sum((observed - mcount)^2, (N - n())*mcount^2)/(N - 1)) %>% 
  select(-N)


# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   strata mcount varcount
#    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1   10.0   1.89    0.861
# 2   20.0   1.33    1.07 
# 3   30.0   2.40    2.30
```

Which matches `df2`

```
df2

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  strata mcount varcount
   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1   10.0   1.89    0.861
2   20.0   1.33    1.07 
3   30.0   2.40    2.30
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I was unsure if sum(()) would work for each row but this works.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `filter` to your pipeline.

```
df2 <- df %>%
 filter(observed != 0) %>%
 group_by(strata) %>%
 summarise(mcount = mean(observed),
          varcount = var(observed))
```

This way you don't need to create an intermediate dataframe.

Comment: This one is more elegant

Comment: From what I can tell, the question is asking how to calculate the mean and variance without using `df`

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear. I don't have the original "df" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logical condition to subset

```
df %>%
   mutate(ind = observed != 0) %>%
   group_by(strata) %>%
   summarise(mcount = mean(observed[ind]), varcount = var(observed[ind]))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  strata mcount varcount
#   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     10   1.89    0.861
#2     20   1.6     0.8  
#3     30   3       0.667
```

NOTE: Using `as.data.frame(cbind` is not recommended as `cbind` can convert it to `matrix`  (matrix can hold only a single class) and this will result in all columns `factor` or `character` with `as.data.frame` (if there are any character columns).  Instead use `data.frame(strata, sites, observed)`